# Working with Visio 2013 file format (.VSDX) in Actionscript 3/flex

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, visio

I am working on an Actionscript/flex based application that can read and edit XML-based Visio 2013 files (.VSDX). Are there any tutorials, documentations or any Actionscript/flex libraries that I can refer to when working with .VSDX files in AS3? Thanks...

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know there are no libraries to do that. But the Visio .VSDX-files in reality are just zipped folders, you can open and check the innards by renaming it to fileName.zip and opening it with Windows Explorer. If there is just a certain file you need to use or modify in the package, you could use a zip-library such as [AS3Commons-zip](http://www.as3commons.org/as3-commons-zip/) to unpack the .vsdx, taking the file you need to modify, doing the edits and rezipping the file.

Answer (score 0):

This project on CodePlex may prove useful as an example of editing this format: http://pkgvisio.codeplex.com/